# Error when building hierarchy with NHibernate - fetch may not be used with scroll() or iterate()

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm relatively new to NHibernate and would like to populate a recursive Category -> Parent Category relationship in a single call but I don't want the entire Category object (I just need the Id and the Name).

I found this http://ayende.com/blog/4151/nhibernate-tips-tricks-efficiently-selecting-a-tree which suggests I should use `JOIN FETCH`. When I do that however I get the error:

> fetch may not be used with scroll() or iterate()

The HQL is as follows:

```
SELECT c.CategoryId as CategoryId, c.Name as Name
FROM Category c JOIN FETCH c.ParentCategory
```

The full code is:

```
var query = session
            .CreateQuery(@"SELECT c.CategoryId as CategoryId, c.Name as Name, c.ParentCategory as ParentCategory
                            FROM Category c JOIN FETCH c.ParentCategory")
            .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
            .Enumerable<Category>();
```

I've also tried adding c.ParentCategory to the select but that doesn't help.

Where am I going wrong? Should I be populating ChildCategories instead of ParentCategory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply because of the `.Enumerable()` call at the end of your statement.

The exception

```
 fetch may not be used with scroll() or iterate()
```

Will be thrown if the query is treated as shallow query. And Enumerable() does put the query into a "shallow state"...

Instead, use `.List()`

Comment: Ela you're a star thanks, it's not populated the object but that definitely sorted that issue thank you very much